# How to pass links to modal triggered by multiple buttons in bootstrap?

Tags: triggers, modal-dialog

I tried the following code found online to trigger one bootstrap modal with multiple buttons.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);  
    var titleData = button.data('title'); 
    var kbtext = button.data('whatever');
    $(this).find('.modal-title').text(titleData);
    $(this).find('.modal-body').text(kbtext);
});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bs-example">
<!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
data-whatever="test 1"    data-title="Test1">Test 1</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
data-whatever=' Click <a href="https://www.math.washington.edu">here</a>'
data-title="Test2">Test 2</button>

<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="text-align:center;">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Window</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            Test body of modal.
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the modal does not properly display the link in Test 2 button. I tried all types of combinations of quotes and escape codes for quotes that I could think of. Nothing worked. What quotes should I use for data-whatever for the second button, that is for

```
data-whatever=' Click <a href="https://www.math.washington.edu">here</a>'
```

In particular, the following did not work

```
  data-whatever=" Click <a href=\"https://www.math.washington.edu\">here</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

In second button you have HTML content `data-whatever=' Click <a href="https://www.math.washington.edu">here</a>'` but you are handling it as `.text();`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever=' Click <a href="https://www.math.washington.edu">here</a>' data-title="Test2">Test 2</button>
```

In script just change this `.text(kbtext);`

```
$(this).find('.modal-body').text(kbtext);
```

to this `.html(kbtext);`

```
$(this).find('.modal-body').html(kbtext);
```

You are passing HTML content as text so that's why the link was showing like below in modal body

```
Click <a href='https://www.math.washington.edu'>here</a>
```

but you want to show content as HTML then use `.html();` method [more information](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp) and link will show like below in modal body

Click [here](https://www.math.washington.edu)

so second button will be like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="Click <a href='https://www.math.washington.edu'>here</a>" data-title="Test2">Test 2</button>
```

and Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);  
        var titleData = button.data('title'); 
        var kbtext = button.data('whatever');
        $(this).find('.modal-title').text(titleData);
        $(this).find('.modal-body').html(kbtext);
    });
});
</script>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ht74y7w9/)